# No code output when writing statements in Visual Studio

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I have visual studio and the Python 2.7 shell.

I can run 5 + 5 in the Python shell which outputs 10.

However if I do 5 + 5 in visual studio, I don't get an output. Why is this the case?

Comment: You are not going to get a answer because the question is to vague. Be more specific, show your code, and talk about how you are using visual studios in tandem with Python.

Comment: a python shell is a line in- line out type of setup (or an interpreter). A script or program on the other hand will not try to display an output for every single line, but they will run still the same. in visual studio, try `print 5 + 5` instead which explicitly displays a line

Answer (score 1):

That is because, when you use the python shell. Shell is executing 5 + 5 when you press enter. Meaning shell executes you commands line by line, as you type them.

On the other hand Visual Studio is not a shell environment, it is an IDE (editor). Which allows you to write the whole python program and then execute it all at once.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell the "addition" is evaluated immediately.

In the editor you have to write:

```
print(5 + 5)
```

You have to tell the program, that it should "print" something in the shell.

More Examples:

```
print("this will be printed")

print("this is a" + "test")
```

In the last example the second string is appended to the first one.

For reference or learning [Python](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Hello,_World!)

Comment: Well, whatever is typed is "evaluated", not "solved"